# How do you set page numbering on the "part" page?

Tags: numbering, counters, parts

I'm trying to get something together for my thesis and part of the organization I would like to use employs the `\part{}` feature (it is to the chapter what a chapter is to a subsection).  The beginning of the paper uses lower cased Roman numerals as page numbering which is fine and the start of the body is supposed to use Arabic numbering.  I've put the page numbering command both before and after `\part{}` but I can't seem to get it Part 1's page to be number 1, it gets a Roman numeral.  Is there a way to fix this?

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage{afterpage} 
\newcommand\blankpage{%
\null \thispagestyle{empty} \addtocounter{page}{0} \newpage} 
\begin{document} 
\title{Title} 
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\maketitle 
\afterpage{\null\newpage} 
\part{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\afterpage{\null\newpage} 
\chapter{} 
Words 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This might depend a bit on what documentclass you're using and which packages you're loading, can you please add a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Hopefully this is minimal enough (Also, I'm not quite sure how to add line breaks on this forum):



\documentclass[12pt,draft,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{
        \null
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \addtocounter{page}{0}
        \newpage}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\part{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\chapter{}

Words

\end{document}

Comment: @AOKi  It is preferable edit the question than left the MWE in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is simply that `\pagenumbering{arabic}` should be ***before***  `\part{}` but after pages with roman count.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft,twoside]{report} 
% Little pages for the MWE
\usepackage[paperheight=12cm,paperwidth=12cm]{geometry} 
\title{Title} 
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle 
\tableofcontents % page i
\newpage % page ii
Another page roman numbered  (page \thepage).
\newpage % page 1
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\part{Some part}
\chapter{Some chapter} 
Words 
\end{document}
```

Note that some `\afterpage{\newpage}` could produce unexpected results with commands as \maketitle, `\part` o `\chapter` that can force a new page.

Note also that in ...

```
\afterpage{\newpage}\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

... unless you have a completely full text page before `\afterpage`, this mean:

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}\newpage
```

However, ...

```
\afterpage{\pagenumbering{arabic}}\part{}
```

... will have the same effect that

```
\newpage\pagenumbering{arabic}\part{}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for providing the help, I think I wasn't clear with the problem, though what you posted is definitely useful to know!  I was wondering if that was possible actually.  My problem has to do with the page numbering, from my MWE, Part I is designed page number iii (the page number's on the bottom of the page) while I want it to be numbered 1 and not iii.  In the MWE, the page labeled 1 is the blank page after Part I and since I want Part I to be page 1, the blank page should be 2.  Was I able to clear up the question?